# Eclipse: An internal error occurred during: "Update Hierarchy"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm following the instructions for creating data flow java project [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse)
When I trying to edit the run configuration as described in the instruction I get the following alert:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Update Hierarchy".
Tried to create a TypeHierarchyPipelineOptionsHierarchy for a Java Project bq-gettingstarted where no PipelineOptions type exists
```

I continued following the instructions ignoring the above but then I get:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching BigQueryJavaGettingStarted (1)".
Tried to create a TypeHierarchyPipelineOptionsHierarchy for a Java Project bq-gettingstarted where no PipelineOptions type exists
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when the `PipelineOptions` type is not present within the classpath of the Eclipse Project. This signifies that the Dataflow `PipelineOptions` class is not on the classpath for your Eclipse project.

If the `com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all` is in the POM, and the project compiles, the maven dependencies may not have been properly resolved. From the project context menu, select the Maven -> Update Project item, check the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkbox, and run the update. This should ensure the Dataflow Jar is on the classpath, which will enable the Dataflow Eclipse Plugin to resolve the base `PipelineOptions` class, and the remainder of the `PipelineOptions` class hierarchy.